# Getting CSP error while deploying superset

Tags: flask, apache-superset

Getting this error while hosting the apache superset

Refused to load the script `https:/domain_name.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/7d0fa10a/cloudflare-static/rocket-loader.min.js` because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
`"script-src 'self' 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-1e4BzhZV9okJrjPnYfx40FvDDs2u6ZeZ'"`. Note that '`strict-dynamic'` is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that
`'script-src-elem'` was not explicitly set, so `'script-src'` is used as a fallback.

The thing i already tried:

```
TALISMAN_ENABLED=False
WTF_CSRF_ENABLED=False
SSH_TUNNELING=False
```

etting talisman_config in superset/config.py

```
TALISMAN_CONFIG = {
   "content_security_policy": {
      "default-src": [
         "'self'"
      ],
      "img-src": [
         "'self'",
         "data:"
      ],
      "worker-src": [
         "'self'",
         "blob:"
      ],
      "connect-src": [
         "'self'",
         "https://api.mapbox.com",
         "https://events.mapbox.com",
         "https://superset.domain.com",
      ],
      "object-src": "'none'",
      "style-src": [
         "'self'",
         "'unsafe-inline'"
      ],
      "script-src": [
         "'self'"
      ],
   },
   "content_security_policy_nonce_in": [],
   "force_https": False,
}
```